# Rename list columns based on list names with purrr

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have a named list and within that list I want to rename their columns based on the names the list comes from.

The probelm with my approach seems to be the `.x` placeholder, which I thought would be my unique list names. But within the `rename_with` function, it seems the `.x` is evaluated within each list data frame and not from the original `.x`. Is there any way I can carry forward the original `.x` (or list names) for renaming?

```
my_list <- list(L1 = data.frame(x=1:3),
                L1 = data.frame(x=1:3),
                L2 = data.frame(x=1:3),
                L2 = data.frame(x=1:3))

my_list |> 
  purrr::map(.x = unique(names(my_list)),
             .f = ~my_list[names(my_list) == .x] |> 
               dplyr::bind_rows() |> 
               dplyr::rename_with(.cols = "x",
                                  .fn   = ~paste0("new_", .x)))
```

expected output:

```
[[1]]
  new_L1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     1
5     2
6     3

[[2]]
  new_L2
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     1
5     2
6     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach I like to use to avoid `.x` conflicts is to use an anonymous function for `map`:

```
unique(names(my_list)) |> 
  # if you want a named list, use set_names
  # purrr::set_names() |>
  purrr::map(\(list_name) my_list[names(my_list) == list_name] |> 
               dplyr::bind_rows() |> 
               dplyr::rename_with(.cols = "x",
                                  .fn   = ~paste0("new_", list_name))
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Just revise 2 places:

- You have set `.x` and `.f` for `map()`, so the first line (`my_list |>`) is redundant. It makes `my_list` thrown into the `...` part of `map()`, which works on nothing.
- In the `.fn` part of `rename_with()`, if you use a formula-style function, the placeholder `.x` will conflict. So you should use a basic function and set a different argument name.

```r
purrr::map(.x = unique(names(my_list)),
           .f = ~ my_list[names(my_list) == .x] |> 
                  dplyr::bind_rows() |> 
                  dplyr::rename_with(.cols = "x",
                                     .fn   = \(col) paste0("new_", .x)))

[[1]]
  new_L1
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      1
5      2
6      3

[[2]]
  new_L2
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      1
5      2
6      3
```

---

You could also use `rename` so that you don't worry about the conflict.

```r
|> dplyr::rename(!!paste0("new_", .x) := x)
```

Comment: In the anonymous function `\(col)` what is the "(col)" part doing, because you don't feed that into the paste0 function.

Comment: @deschen the `col` represents the column name, i.e. `"x"`, and it has no effect in this anonymous function. It exists just to distinguish with `.x`.

Comment: It's doing nothing (it has the value of the renamed value, but in your case this is not needed), but `rename_with` expects that the function used has an argument. See also how in my solution I use the lambda syntax (`~`) which automatically results in a `.x`, but I don't use it in the function.

Comment: I see. In any case, tough decision on choosing an accepted answer here. I decided for @starja's solution, because I could somehow follow that solution a bit better because the argument "list_name" in that anonymous function was carried forward to the rename_with. However, IMO, both solutions deserve the credit as an accepted answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
imap(my_list,
     ~ .x %>%
     rename_with(function(listnames) paste0("new_", .y), everything())) 

$L1
  new_L1
1      1
2      2
3      3

$L1
  new_L1
1      1
2      2
3      3

$L2
  new_L2
1      1
2      2
3      3

$L2
  new_L2
1      1
2      2
3      3
```

If you need an unnamed list:

```
imap(my_list,
     ~ .x %>%
     rename_with(function(listnames) paste0("new_", .y), everything())) %>%
 unname()
```